# Como puedo compara 2 datos de un datagridview

Tags: c#, if, datagrid

Hola amigos estoy intentando comparar de un registro de grid, 2 valores.

```
 DataGridViewRow row = dgvList.Rows[idx];

            if (row.Cells[3].Value.Equals(row.Cells[5].Value.ToString())) {
                var alta = Application.OpenForms.OfType<AltaEnInventario>().Single();
                alta.CerrarAlta();
            }
```

para llamar una funcion pero esta nunca entra..
los valores que se encuentran al debuggear, son

```
 2.00 y 2.00
```

estoy tratando de realizar una funcion, que cuando el dato de del indice 3 sea igual al de 5, este llame un metodo que tengo. pero nunca entra

pero nunca entra en la sentencia de control. alguna otra sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que sucede es que uno lo traes como `ToString()` y al primero no entonces nunca son compatibles, deberia ser asi:

DataGridViewRow row = dgvList.Rows[idx];

```
        if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals(row.Cells[5].Value.ToString())) {
            var alta = Application.OpenForms.OfType<AltaEnInventario>().Single();
            alta.CerrarAlta();
        }
```

espero te sirva amigo y la marques, By: JJ

Comment: No amigo, le agregue al equals,toString y no entra en la centencia

Comment: bro, lo que creo que debe estar infligiendo en que no entre a if es que en la primera liena, ya miraste su lo que trae esta fila [DataGridViewRow row = dgvList.Rows[idx];] si corresponde a las filas que quieres comparar ?

Comment: si funciono amigo.

Comment: me alegro muchisimo bro.... exitos!